# How (or where) do I find an airfoil optimized for low reynolds numbers (100,000~150,000)?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airfoil

Looking to build a RC plane. Because the span is going to be small and the speed relatively low, I estimate the R-number to be around 100,000. Is there an airfoil optimized for that range of Reynold's Number?

Answer (score 3):

Try the HQ series from the [UIUC Airfoil Data Site](http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads.html). That is HQ as in [Helmut Quabeck (model airfoils)](http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord_database.html#I), not Horstmann-Quast (those would be glider airfoils).

Another possible source is the [website of Martin Hepperle](http://www.mh-aerotools.de/airfoils/index.htm).

Unfortunately, there is not one, but hundreds of airfoils optimized for the model aircraft range of Reynolds numbers. To be any more specific, I would need to know more about how you plan to use that model:

- Will it be a glider with a low wing loading, trying to stay aloft as long as possible?
- Will it be a fast glider for ridge racing?
- Will it be a powered model for aerobatics?

Each case will need different airfoils.

Comment: Right... I am thinking of a medium-slow speed (10-15m/s) powered plane mainly geared for endurance. I suppose it will be closer in design to a glider. Thanks!